# Autofac - mixed InstancePerHttpRequest and asynchronous scope

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scope, autofac

I am building a four-layer system with MVC3 as the main front end, but containing long-running tasks that are run asynchronously by the service layer and report progress, which MVV will show using Ajax. I am using Autofac for dependency injection (DI) mainly because the interface and documentation is good and because its fast (see this excellent study on [DI speed](http://philipm.at/2011/0808/) by Philip Mateescu).

My question is about how to set up Autofac to handle the two scopes of the injected items, i.e. the MVC3 dependencies have to be PerHttpRequest but the async task dependencies need to be InstancePerLifetimeScope.

Clearly the service layer will need to use a separate DI to resolve the long-running task's dependencies. What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure the second part of your question is very clear. Can you provide some code snippets or additional clarification?

Comment: Hi Travis, Thanks for looking at this and sorry, the second question was a bit vague. I have found more information elsewhere and have therefore removed my second question as it was a bit too complicated to list in a few lines. I have left the original information up as it might be useful to others. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update - June 2014

I have updated this answer as the best practice on using AutoFac has moved on, plus changes in MVC. The change is that best practice in AutoFac is now to define any instances that need to last for the whole lifetime of the access, in the case of MVC the HttpRequest, by using the .InstancePerLifetimeScope() suffix. See below for an example:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().As<IMyDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Having done that you no longer need to specify the name of the new lifetime scope you are creating inside the task (see original answer, which has been updated, below).

Here are a few other notes about tasking in MVC that you might find useful:

- If you are using the new async/await then do don't need a new lifetime scope. Aysnc/await keeps the current context and simply freeing up the thread to improve the performance of the web under load.
- If you really do want to run something in the background then be warned - there are some issues. I suggest you read this [helpful blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) from the expert on async, Stephen Cleary.
- One really useful combination is using SignalR in combination with MVC to report progress and allow user cancel. This has worked well for me.

---

**Original post, but updated (note: you must register lifetime scope instances as shown above)**

I have found how to handle an async task with dependencies though the Google Autofac group. It turns out that you can access the MVC level container and then create a new lifetime scope of the resolve. There are a number of ways of doing it but this [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/autofac/gJYDDls981A) by Alex Meyer-Gleaves (who is an expert) provides the answer. Alex suggests the following code below for running a task that has a different scope.

```
public void Run<T>(Action<T> action)
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
  {
    using (var container = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current
                           .ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var service = container.Resolve<T>();
        action(service);
    }
  });
}
```

There is a link to a more detailed blog post [here](http://aboutcode.net/2010/11/01/start-background-tasks-from-mvc-actions-using-autofac.html) on the subject in Alex's post which is also very useful.

Comment: Please add the answer here as an answer rather than editing your question. That is the best way for the Stack Overflow question and answer format. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this Jon Smith. You wouldn't happen to have a link on the InstancePerLifetimeScope best practice with MVC + Autofac to hand would you? I looked [here](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/BestPractices) but no joy...

Comment: Hi @Johnny Reilly. Its under Controlling Scope and Lifetime -> Instance Scope in the wiki. https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope. Hope that helps.